# Objective c different date format

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am developing an ios application with objective c. I use current date for my business.

```
NSDateFormatter *df1=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
[df1 setDateFormat:@"ddyymmssHHMMssHHyyddMMmm"];
NSString *key=[df1 stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
NSLog(@"%@",key);
```

Some iPhone device generate this below.

> 16186:43:26 PM116 PM (second: 26)18161143

But I want this formatted value. That's how all devices generate.

> 121846281112281118121246

Why do some iPhone devices return incorrect results?

Comment: There might be some issues due to locale. Set en_US_posix: `[df1 setLocale:[NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];`.

Comment: What kind of iPhone devices?